# CakePhp condition with related HABTM model

Tags: cakephp, join, find, conditional-statements, has-and-belongs-to-many

I've got the two Models: *Article* and *Hashtag* with a HABTM relation.
So in my database there are the tables **articles** (*id,text,etc.*), **hashtags** (*id,value*) and the join table **articles_hashtags** (*article_id,hashtag_id*).
Now I want to find all articles with a given hashtag_id together with other conditions..
My attempt was first to find all articles with a given hashtag, to save them in an array:

`$this->query("SELECT * FROM articles_hashtags WHERE hashtag_id=" . $hashtagId;");`

and after that find articles with the other conditions,sorting etc in a second query like this:

```
 $this->find('all', array('conditions' => array("Articles.id" => $articleIds),...
```

is it possible to find articles with a hashtag condition in one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use `->query()`.  It's only needed if you're doing something unusual (which this isn't).

There are a number of ways you could do what you're looking to do.  The easiest is probably this:

```
//Hashtag model
$this->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => $hashtagId
    ),
    'contain' => array(
        'Article'
    )
));
```

This uses [CakePHP's Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).  Get used to it - it's amazing.

Or, you could use [JOINs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#joining-tables).

Or, you could create a model for your HABTM association "ArticleHashtag" and use that to retrieve either (likely using Containable again).

Comment: I updated the answer to do a 'first' find instead of an 'all' find.  There's no reason for an 'all' if you're using the id as a condition.